# Why is there a syntax error on the import statement

Tags: python

[image]I've tried running this code but it returns an error saying I have a syntax error particularly the first import statement. However I was able to solve this problem by using **.format(message)** instead of **f**. Can someone explain why is this the case?

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    elif 'hello' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send(f'hello {0.author.mention}')
```

Comment: what does `f` or `format(message)` have to do with the `import` on line 1? Nothing from what I can see. Either there is a crucial bit of information you have omitted or something *very* strange is going on

Comment: Can you post the actual error ?

Comment: Changing the f-string can't affect the `import` statement.

Comment: If you're getting an error from the f-string, it's probably because you're not using python 3.6+.

Comment: You did not get a syntax error on the `import` statement.  Your `f` string is wrong; it should be `f'hello {message.author.mention}'`.

Comment: Which python version are you using? f-strings were introduced in python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

`python -m pip install discord.py`

do this before

```
python -m pip install discord.py
import discord
```